# unity5 iOS gamecenter login popup changing game orientation to portrait

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine

I am working on a unity2d game which runs in landscape mode, targeting iOS devices. 
After integrating game center plugin for iOS, and while running in device, I accidentally kept the device in portrait mode. Game center login splash popped out as expected and after login, entire game orientation changed to portrait mode.

```
Social.localUser.Authenticate(OnAuth);
```

I then tried placing this function in UnityApp...Controller.m file

```
- (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication*)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow*)window
{
 return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight;
}
```

> After making this change, app started crashing once game center attempts to login, keeping the device in portrait mode

Any workaround or fix available for this ?

UPDATE 1:
 I tried to disable game center when app runs keeping the device in portrait mode using the below code.

```
if( Input.deviceOrientation == DeviceOrientation.LandscapeLeft || Input.deviceOrientation == DeviceOrientation.LandscapeRight ) {
   Social.localUser.Authenticate(OnAuth);
}
```

Regardless of the device orientation, "if" condition always succeeded and showing the game center... and turns my game to portrait again:(